# Replace word in string in Python while keeping formatting

Tags: python, string, list, replace

I have a python script that sends an email, but it needs to replace two words. Whenever it replaces them, it breaks the formatting. As an example, the message `hello how are you my app is [name] and the url is [url]` after being run with this script then sends the email as

```
hello how are you my app is AppName
 and the app url is www.example.com
```

Currently I am using `message.replace("[name]", name).replace("[url]", url)`

Comment: May be `name` contains a trailing newline. try: `message.replace("[name]", name.rstrip())...`

Comment: what do you mean "breaks formatting", is the template line supposed to be of fixed width or what, its not clear. Every replace method will do the same unless you mean sth else (e.g fixed width) in whice case you will have to loop through and re-adjust spaces or sth like that

Answer (score 0):

use the basic python method for inserting variables into a string

```
'hello how are you my app is %s and the app url is %s' % (appName, www.example.com)
```

observe this section in learn python the hard way :)
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex6.html